# The clickhouse cluster cannot create any tables

Tags: create-table, clickhouse

Code: 107. DB::Exception: There was an error on [ck1:9000]: Code: 107. DB::ErrnoException: Cannot open file /data/clickhouse/store/76b/76b93482-a138-42fc-9969-e608641273be/zxc_sig.sql.tmp, errno: 2, strerror: No such file or directory. (FILE_DOESNT_EXIST) (version 22.11.2.30 (official build)). (FILE_DOESNT_EXIST) (version 22.11.2.30 (official build))
, server ClickHouseNode [uri=http://10.31.0.57:8123/default, options={use_server_time_zone=false,use_time_zone=false}]@619095544

No matter what table I create, this error will be fixed and displayed.

Why?

I cleared the data directory and reinstalled the clickhouse cluster. By the way, I also deleted the/clickhouse node on the zookeeper, but the error reported was still this, even the UUID did not change.

Comment: I modified the directory where the data files are stored. After restarting, the same error still occurred, and the prompt did not change the directory where the data files are stored. This is too strange

Comment: Do you have any .sql files lingering in the /metadata folder? Those get executed at startup. If there's a file in there that shouldn't be there...just delete it.

Comment: Hi cnzxc - this error could occur for quite a few different reasons, and I think we'll need to understand more about your setup. Some questions include: did this occur on the first table you tried to create? which table engine are you using? what filesystem type are you using for /data and is it writable? can you provide more of the clickhouse server logs? I'd suggest opening a case with ClickHouse Support at https://clickhouse.cloud/support to provide more details privately

Comment: `df -h /data/`

/data/ shall be writable and have ext4 file system

do you use windows + wsl?